# Batch script to conditionally delete files

Tags: windows, batch, script, filenames

Owners of Nokia Lumia 1020 know it can be set to store captured photos at full resolution, but the reduced size photos are also stored.
I would like to have a script to automatically delete all the low resolution versions.

The filenames are kind of the following:

```
WP_20150303_17_20_38_Pro.jpg
WP_20150303_17_20_38_Pro__highres.jpg
WP_20150303_17_21_21_Pro.jpg
WP_20150303_17_21_21_Pro__highres.jpg
WP_20150303_17_21_32_Pro.jpg
WP_20150303_17_21_32_Pro__highres.jpg
WP_20150303_17_22_47_Pro.jpg
WP_20150303_17_22_47_Pro__highres.jpg
WP_20150303_17_28_14_Pro.jpg
WP_20150303_17_28_14_Pro__highres.jpg
```

I could delete *_pro.jpg, but then there is a risk that what if there is no high resolution version at all.
How can I write a script that would first check if there is a highres file present and only then delete lowresolution version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a batch file. Start here: [Loop command: against the results of another command](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) and here: [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)

```
For /F "tokens=*" %%G in ('dir /b *_pro.jpg') do (
   echo %%~dpnG
)
```

Now you could change  `echo %%~dpnG` to

```
   if exist "%%~dpnG__highres.jpg" echo del "%%~dpnxG"
```

or even to

```
   if exist "%%~dpnG__highres.jpg" (
        echo del "%%~dpnxG"
   ) else (
        echo retain %%~dpnxG
   )
```

Thoroughly check the output (better twice) and substitute `echo del` with `del`.

Add `/s` switch to `dir` command as follows: `dir /b /s *_pro.jpg` to treat files in subfolders as well.

Answer (score 0):

The .bat file I use:

```
    @Echo off
For /F "tokens=*" %%G in ('dir /s /b *_pro.jpg') do (
    if exist "%%~dpnG__highres.jpg" (
        echo delete %%~dpnxG
   ) else (
        echo retain %%~dpnxG
   )
)

Echo.
Echo _________________________________________________
Echo.

 Echo Do you really want to delete these files (Y/N)?
CHOICE /C YN /N 
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 goto doend
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 goto doerase
exit

:doerase
For /F "tokens=*" %%G in ('dir /s /b *_pro.jpg') do (
    if exist "%%~dpnG__highres.jpg" (
        del "%%~dpnxG"
   ) else (
        REM echo retain %%~dpnxG
   )
)

:doend
pause
```